# Cyclical vibration frequency on some of the strings?

Tags: electric-guitar, tuning, setup

I have a yamaha 311h, I was playing around in Amplitube ultra tuner and noticed something weird with the tuning of the 4th, 2nd and 1st strings.

All of these strings are cycling in vibration compared to all the rest of the strings which have a very constant, flat response.

6th string, low E https://postimg.cc/NyF057P4

5th string https://postimg.cc/185FrFjg

4th string https://postimg.cc/dD6rknWM

3rd string https://postimg.cc/xXv08pRM

2nd string https://postimg.cc/sQqX7QZh

It's also pretty strange that at the 12th fret the tuning is very stable for the 4th string:
4th string, 12th fret https://postimg.cc/LY8m8rm5

Plus, 6th and 5th string are at +10 when fretted on 12th string compared to open string tuning.

What could be causing this and how to fix it please?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a typical intonation set up problem, where the saddles on the bridge are not adjusted proerly.

When a 12th fret harmonic is at the same pitch as the fretted string (again 12th), all is good. Simple adjustment with an Allen key on that guitar, I think.

Comment: MIght be worth a few sentences about the physics - wrong string length can lead to competing induced resonances among strings, which leads to that sort of pitch oscillation.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - you're talking a foreign language - I only do simple! Sounds like it could be your few sentences?